# Is there `is` functionality for the underlying types held by `TAny`?

Tags: reflection, nim-lang

I can access the fields of an object at runtime using `TAny` and I know that there's `.kind`, which will give me the correct `TAnyKind` but is there a method that will let me query specific user-defined types or concepts like the `is` operator does?

Like...

```
my_any is FooObject
```

or...

```
my_any is BarConcept
```

Or is there something else that would be better to use than `TAny` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic Nim way would be to rely on polymorphic types such as `ref RootObj` or `ptr RootObj` and use the `of operator` to perform the type checking. It's briefly documented in the [Object and Tuples Types](http://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-tuples-and-object-types) section in the manual.

If you really need to use `TAny`, there is no supported way to do what you want at the moment, but you can add the following proc to typeinfo.nim, which is part of the system module:

```
proc isInstanceOf*(a: Any, T: typedesc): bool =
  if a.rawType.kind != tyObject: return false
  var tval: T
  var targetType = cast[PNimType](tval.getTypeInfo)
  var argType = a.rawType

  while argType != targetType:
    if argType == nil: return false
    argType = argType.base

  return true
```

Here is an example for using the proc:

```
import typeinfo

type
  Foo = object of RootObj
    x: int

  FooDerived = object of Foo
    y: int

  Bar = object of RootObj
    s: string

var obj = FooDerived(x: 1, y: 2)

var objAny = obj.toAny

echo objAny.isInstanceOf(Bar)
echo objAny.isInstanceOf(Foo)
echo objAny.isInstanceOf(FooDerived)
```

The code will print:

```
false
true
true
```

Type checking of concepts is a strictly compile-time mechanism and it doesn't have a run-time equivalent.

Comment: Thanks zah. Yeah, I need a `TAny` for this particular situation. I tried for a couple hours yesterday to make a proc in `typeinfo` like your `isInstanceOf()` but couldn't get it right, so thank you for the implementation.

Comment: Strange... The `a.rawType.kind` is a `tyTuple` if the object doesn't inherit from `RootObj` (or if it doesn't have `{.inheritable.}`).